# How to create a reset button in a JS game?

Tags: javascript, function, reset

I almost finished my first JS game ( rock, paper , scissors) and I'm struggling to create a reset button that just takes the scores and the number of the rounds to 0. Initially I thought that I solved by creating a function that resets the number in the HTML but it doesn't reset them in JS.

Here is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/r1osmpec/

```
function reset(){
  let rounds = 0;
  let userScore = 0;
  let computerScore = 0;
  let ties = 0;
  round_number.innerHTML = 'Round: '
  ties_number.innerHTML = '0'
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = '0'
  userScore_span.innerHTML = '0'
}
```

I tried to in the function reset() to put the values to 0 again but it has no effect.

Thank you!

Comment: `let` is for declaring new variables inside the scope of `reset`. Remove the `let`s.

Comment: Remove the `let` inside your `reset` function, it is declaring new variables

Comment: maybe [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or similar may help you structurate your application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `let` before your variables so that your function looks like this:

```
function reset(){
  rounds = 0;
  userScore = 0;
  computerScore = 0;
  ties = 0;
  round_number.innerHTML = 'Round: '
  ties_number.innerHTML = '0'
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = '0'
  userScore_span.innerHTML = '0'
}
```

As you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) the keyword `let` creates a new variable in the current context and doesn't reference to other variables. Because of that you were just creating new variables with the value `0` and not editing your existing vars.